# How to mix flog.fatal and stop

Tags: r, logging, error-handling

I am starting to use the [futile.logger](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/futile.logger/index.html) package. There is a nice FATAL error logging that I would like to use in conjuction with `stop`.
But say I do :

```
stop(flog.fatal('crash for some reason'))
```

I get

```
[FATAL] [2015-07-06 22:46:54] [base.stop] crash for some reason

Error: 
[FATAL] [2015-07-06 22:46:54] [base.stop] crash for some reason
```

How can I just `stop` (abort the program), after logging what the `flog.fatal` logged

So `[FATAL] [2015-07-06 22:46:54] [base.stop] crash for some reason` and that's it

Answer (score 0):

Your question as stated seems trivial?  Just do

```
flog.fatal('crash for some reason'); stop()
```

?

(I personally find futile.logger more useful for writing text messages to a file, not to the console, but also print the messages to the console with R's conditions `message(), warning(), stop()` etc.

The value returned by flog.fatal is a character vector (length 1) which stop prints.

```
res <- flog.fatal('crash for some reason')
print(res)
```

Comment: R> flog.fatal('crash for some reason'); stop()
FATAL [2017-08-22 03:16:33] crash for some reason
Error: (that's not the same as only the flog message)

Answer (score 0):

As alternative you can use `ftry` function from the `futile.logger` package.

```
> futile.logger::ftry(log("a"))
ERROR [2017-08-22 10:50:51] non-numeric argument to mathematical function
Error in log("a") : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```